# How to enable PyCharm autocompletion for imported library (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, discord, discord.py

How do I enable method autocompletion for discord.py in PyCharm? Until now I've been doing it the hard way by looking at the documentation and I didn't even know that autocomplete for a library existed. So how do I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my case was to first create a new interpreter as a new virtual environment, copy over all of the libraries I needed (there is an option to inherit all of the libraries from the previous interpreter while setting up the new one) and then follow method 3 from above. I hope this helps anyone in the future!

Comment: Where exactly is that option to "inherit all of the libraries from previous one"?

Answer (score 2):

Code completion (intellisense) can be found from the settings menu:

- `Ctrl + alt + s` to bring up the settings

  [image]
- Click on the dropdown for `Editor` -> `General`, and then select `Code Completion`

  [image]
- And here you're able to enable and customise the settings as you wish.

---

Try selecting `File` -> `Invalidate caches / Restart...` if it doesn't work.

[image]

If that still doesn't work, go into your settings, `Project Structure`, direct yourself to the `discord` folder and mark it as a source:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't show an option for discord.py autocomplete. The only autocomplete suggestions that I get are from previously used methods for the same object.

Comment: @Pudge Edited the answer with a couple more ideas!

Comment: I tried the first 2 options but for the third one, I cannot find any discord folder. I guess this is what happens when you set everything up with a tutorial in the beginning and don't know how to navigate anything...

Comment: I've started a [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215194/room-for-diggy-and-pudge) for us to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Bro, make sure you fill on_message() correctly. You have to mention a type of message async def receives: `message: discord.Message`

I had that problem and after mentioning the type it **disappeared** :)

P.S. I even have just created an account on Stack Overflow to write here this simple solution