# Pycharm can't autofill or find usage of tkinter parameters(text, padx,pady)

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, autofill

Pycharm can't autofill or find usage of tkinter variables. It doesn't autofill `text,padx,pady,column,row`(parameters) and others but it can autofill values like "state=DISABLED" it only fills DISABLED part.

```
label2 = Label(root, text="boredom")
```

Note: This question might be hard to understand and maybe I understood it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if anything in [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#troubleshooting) helps, but it might be worth a look. I'm much more familiar with VS Code I'm afraid

Comment: @JRiggles this documentation is about more general issues my problem is more specific because code completion works but in tkinter it doesn't work but thanks

Comment: Ah darn...you may have to explicitly tell PyCharm to add autocompletions for tkinter (by pointing it at the tkinter lib perhaps), but I'm not sure how to do that offhand. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159638/how-to-enable-pycharm-autocompletion-for-imported-library-discord-py) help at all?

Comment: @JRiggles I thought about that but button (root, state=DİSABLED) is tkinter special too but it suggests DİSABLED,NORMAL,ACTİVE

Comment: `DISABLED`, `NORMAL` and `ACTIVE` are all valid "constants" in tkinter (they're equivalent to the strings `'disabled'`, `'normal'` and `'active'`). Out of curiosity, are you doing `import tkinter as tk` or `from tkinter import *` - autocomplete may have a hard time if you're using a star import, and I suspect that's your problem (one of several reasons to avoid star imports...)

Comment: @JRiggles I used star(*) to import it. import tkinter as tk doesn't work in pycharm but it might be reason thanks.

Comment: If you do `import tkinter as tk` you'll have to give your widgets the `tk` namespace prefix, e.g.: `tk.Tk`, `tk.Label`, etc. But I assume you've figured that part out if it's working! Glad I could help out.